# Grep string start with . or whitespace

Tags: bash, grep, prefix

I'm running a script that get an argument `$1`

I want to find all strings that start with either space or `.` before that argument.
and end with either `.` or `%`

ex:

if `$1` is Table1 then

1)  "Table1" 
 2) " Table1" 
 3) "**.**Table1" 
 4) "Table1**.**" 
 5) "**.**Table1." 
 6) " Table1**.**" 
 7) "**.**Table1%" 
 8) " Table1%"

should be good

Comment: why does 1 match? it does not start with either a . or a space.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: 1 is part of the argument name "Table1", i'm passing it to .run file that have the grep in it

Comment: The grep command uses basic regular expressions.  Look at the meanings of the following: "." (match any character), "\" (escape the behavior of a character, "(" and ")" (grouping), "[" and "]" (character sets), and "|" (alternatives).  What expressions have you tried?

Comment: something like 
[\ * | \.*]$1[\.*|'%'*]

and 

[\ * | \.*]$1 | $1[\.*|'%'*]

Comment: i manage to get the first part :

'([\.]|[:blank:])'|$1

but the tail isn't working

Comment: something like 

'([\.]|[:blank:])'|$1|'([\%]|[:blank:]|[\.])'

Comment: `sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/[.]//g' -e 's/[%]//g'`

Comment: [edit] your question providing proper input (use the tools to format properly!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat input_file.txt
Table1
 Table1
.Table1
Table1.
.Table1.
 Table1.
.Table1%
 Table1%
# the following should not match:
-Table1%
.Table1-
&Table1
Table10
myTable1
```

If by "finding all strings" you mean "whole lines", it is quite simple:

```
$ grep "^[. ]\?$1[.%]\?$" input_file.txt
```

If you mean matching strings occurring everywhere in a line, then it gets more complex since you have included the plain word "Table1" in your desired matches (match (1.) in your description). I would go with a 2-step approach.

First get all lines containing "Table1" as a word (`grep -w`).
Then filter out (`grep -v`) everything you don't want to be matched:

```
  $ grep -w "$1" input_file.txt |  
    grep -v "[^ .]\+$1" | 
    grep -v "$1[^.%]\+"
```

or more compact:

```
 $ grep -w "$1" input_file.txt | grep -v "[^ .]\+$1\|$1[^.%]\+"
```

result:

```
Table1
 Table1
.Table1
Table1.
.Table1.
 Table1.
.Table1%
 Table1%
```

`grep -v "[^ .]\+$1"` : means Filter-out (`-v`) previous-matches which start with a least one character other than "space" or "."

If you want to match any "whitespace" (e.g. tabs) and not only the common literal "space", replace the literal space " "  in the grep patterns above with `[:space:]`

Comment: I meant matching strings occurring everywhere in a line .. 
basically i'm looking for all occurrences for that table name without get confused with other names that is not the table.
like a function get_table1 or so ..  

i have this : 

grep -v "^--" *.*  | grep -i --color=always -E $1 | nl

Comment: So, you should use the second method. You can always save this as a function : `function get_table() { grep -w "$1" | grep -v "[^ .]\+$1\|$1[^.%]\+" ; }`  
 and call it as such:  `grep -v "^--" . | get_table "Table1"`